# Почему не банят поисковые боты Яндекса, Гугла и т.п.?

Tags: php, seo, поисковые-системы

У меня есть идея написать небольшой поисковик под свои задачи, сделал ряд парсеров для анализа нужных мне сайтов, но их очень быстро банят. Возник вопрос: как работает поисковой бот (к примеру Яндекса)? Ведь насколько я понимаю поисковой бот это тот же самый парсер, и ему нужно обойти сайт, но при этом сайты его не блокируют. Помогите разобраться как поисковые боты обходят сайты.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать Custom Search Element Control API https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element

Answer (score 0):

Заходят на главную страницу сайта и следуют по всем ссылкам на ней. На внутренних точно так же. 
У вас же проблема не с тем, как работает, а "почему не банят". Потому, что яндекс/гугл. Их узнают по заголовкам запроса и/или reverse DNS и если сайт хочет быть проиндексированным, то вынужден не блокировать поисковых роботов. 
Чтобы вас не блокировали можно:

1. использовать прокси
2. обходить сайты очень аккуратно, а не 5 потоков по 200 url/s
3. использовать другой хостинг. Выш IP, с которого ходит бот может быть в каком-то блек-листе.